# Change of variable (Fourier Transform related)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a problem below...

[image]

The solution offered to this particular question (1)a)) simply state the change of variable ksi to by to yield the result, I'm failing miserably to see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, write formula from $\textbf{[1]}$ for $x=yb$, that means:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i \xi yb}}{1+\xi^2}\; d\xi =\pi e^{-b|y|}$$

Next change of variables in integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i \xi yb}}{1+\xi^2}\; d\xi$$

Putting $\xi=\frac{\xi}{b}$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i \xi yb}}{1+\xi^2}\; d\xi=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b}\frac{e^{i \xi y}}{1+\frac{\xi^2}{b^2}}\; d\xi$$

Next (simple multiplying by $\frac{b}{b}=1$):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b}\frac{e^{i \xi y}}{1+\frac{\xi^2}{b^2}}\; d\xi=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}b\frac{e^{i \xi y}}{b^2+\xi^2}\; d\xi$$

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking $s = \frac{\xi}{b}$ so the denominator looks as the denominator of the integral you know how to solve. Then, think using the condition "for any $x \in \mathbb{R} $".